# Angular2- Location without routing?

Tags: angular

How do I monitor and set URL search params without routing?

'Location' and seems to have what I want. However I get this error:

> Error: No provider for Location!

With the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location, HashLocationStrategy } from "@angular/common";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  providers: [HashLocationStrategy]
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location){}
}
```

How do I know which provider it wants? And is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: can you share why you dont want the help from the route service?

Comment: Which version of Angular2 are you using? Location was moved into common in 2.0.0-beta.16 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta16-2016-04-26

Comment: @JayChase that's the version I'm using

Comment: @x0a  sorry that should have been '@angular/platform/common" for 2.0.0-beta.16. You can then us location.go() (it is @angular/common in 2.0.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it once. To implement [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html) you will have to implements it like that in your **MainComponent:**

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {
    Location,
    LocationStrategy,
    HashLocationStrategy,
    APP_BASE_HREF
} from '@angular/common';
import {provide} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated'

import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(
    AppComponent
    , [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS
        ,ROUTER_PROVIDERS
        , provide(APP_BASE_HREF, { useValue: '/' })     
        , provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })]
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty old question, active though as people still visiting. According to Angular documentation:

> It's better to use Router service to trigger route changes. Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing.

@Nathaniel's response is a bit outdated.

**Using Location** (no Router)

Here is an updated implementation:

```
import { Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'path-location',
   providers: [Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
   template: `
      Current URL is: <code>{{location.path()}}</code><br>
      Normalize: <code>/foo/bar/</code> is: <code>{{location.normalize('foo/bar')}}</code><br>
   `
})
export class LocationComponent {

   location: Location;

   constructor(location: Location) { this.location = location; }
}
```

Three `LocationStrategy` are available depending on the use case:

- HashLocationStrategy    - to deal with hash fragment of the browser's URL
- PathLocationStrategy    - to deal with path of the browser's URL
- MockLocationStrategy    - for testing/simulations

**Using Router**

Angular Router offers a straight-forward approach as well. The only thing you need to do is to import `RouterModule` to your `AppModule` as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot([])],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and then use `ActivatedRoute` to get your search parameters.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';     // optional if you're a fan of rxjs

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-overview',
    templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./overview.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {

   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
       this.route.params.first().subscribe(params => {
           if (params._query) {
               // Pass parameters: http://your.app.com?_query=myquery
               // Use _query and/or any other parameters you need here
           }
       });
   }
}
```

Hope it helps