# Angular2 - read url location at bootstrap

Tags: angular

My question is similar to [Angular2- Location without routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521589/angular2-location-without-routing) but that answer does not seem to work any more. I store the state of my app in the url (to enable deep linking), and just need to read it at bootstrap. No routing needed.

The official angular docs make it look simple - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html - so I tried

```
constructor(public location: Location, public locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {

     console.log(this.location.path()
        .split('/'));
```

except that this gives me an error `Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:0 caused by: No provider for Location!`

**How and where do I set up the necessary `provider`?**

Comment: What does "but that answer does not seem to work any more" mean exactly?

Comment: E.g. `provide` no longer seems to exist

Comment: Just change `provide(...)` to `{provide: ... }`

Comment: Try to inject `PlatformLocation` instead of `Location`

Comment: `Location` should also be provided by `BrowserModule` and `CommonModule` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

Comment: Thanks, I switched to PlatformLocation and that seems to be helping a lot!! I now look for  this.location.pathname.split('/').slice(2)[0]; to get the third element in location, as /recommendations/budget  gets mapped to ["", "recommendations", "budget"]